# Downloaded 1996 Emacs (19.34), consulted INSTALL, no `configure` file

Tags: build

I'm trying to build Emacs 19.34 (which dates from 1996) because I'm interested in its historical behaviour.  I've unpacked the archive and read the INSTALL file.  That file seems to say that I should run the configure script in the same directory, but there is no such script.

What (probably obvious) thing am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

`configure` is a file generated from `configure.in`:

```
dnl  Autoconf script for GNU Emacs
dnl To rebuild the `configure' script from this, execute the command
dnl     autoconf
```

Although I thought tarballs should usually come with it pre-generated, did you download the tarball from git?

It's possible that you will run into problems trying this with a current `autoconf` version.  It looks like you could use `configure1.in` as `configure` if you fail to generate it yourself.

Comment: I downloaded the tarball from [here](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tag/?h=emacs-19.34).  Unpacking the tarball resulted in a `configure.in` but no `configure`.  It also resulted in the `INSTALL` I've been working from.  Which, I have just discovered, does mention `autoconf`, but about 400 lines after it tells me to run `configure`.  Thanks!

Comment: In newer Emacs this is explained in `INSTALL.repo`, but there wasn't any repo back then. If you download the tarball from https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/emacs/, it comes with a `configure` file.

Comment: Thanks!  It turns out I should have read `INSTALL` more closely.  It has a later section on configuring "by hand".  So I might edit your answer accordingly.

Comment: I think the "by hand" section should only be needed if running `./configure` fails.

Comment: Running `./configure` was failing in a sense.  I'll see how I go with following the instructions in `INSTALL`.  If that doesn't work I'll try your advice to copy `configure.in` to `configure`.